# SQS Java Listener cluster nodes duplicate data created on a memory heap issue

Tags: java, jms, listener, heap-memory, amazon-sqs

We have an external system that pushes data to SQS, and the consumer is another java service, that listens and created the requests, distributes the tasks, then acknowledges the SQS.

But a memory heap issue occurred a time, and from the logs, it is understood that the java consumer consumed multiple times the Queue, but all times throws a memory exception, and seems saved all later.
So the Q didn't get acknowledged, so data was available for the consumer. The db commits happened after a certain while only.

The strategy to avoid this kind of issue, what approach we can take?
Exception Handling, SQS retry mechanism change, check exists kind of validation..?

Comment: What does this have to do with JMS? Are your clients using the JMS API to interact with SQS?

Comment: The sqs is listened by jms listener in the subscriber app.